# Convert date to another format Scala Spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, to-date

I am reading a CSV that contains two types of date:

- dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss -> 13-Dec-2019 17:10:00
- dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm -> 11/02/2020 17:33

**I am trying to transform all dates of the first type into the second type but I can't find a good solution. I am trying this**:

```
val pr_date = readeve.withColumn("Date", when(to_date(col("Date"),"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").isNotNull,
      to_date(col("Date"),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")))
pr_date.show(25)
```

And I get the entire Date column as null values:

[image: null values]

I am trying with this function:

```
 def to_date_(col: Column,
            formats: Seq[String] = Seq("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")) = {
    coalesce(formats.map(f => to_date(col, f)): _*)
 }
 
 val p2 = readeve.withColumn("Date",to_date_(readeve.col(("Date")))).show(125)
```

And in the first type of date i get nulls too:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? (*new with Scala Spark*)

*Scala version: 2.11.7
Spark version: 2.4.3*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below? Note that `17` is `HH`, not `hh`. Also try `to_timestamp` instead of `to_date` because you want to keep the time.

```
val pr_date = readeve.withColumn(
    "Date",
    coalesce(
        date_format(to_timestamp(col("Date"),"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
        date_format(to_timestamp(col("Date"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    )
)
```